# Devel Generate - character length

Tags: 8

I like Devel Generate. But I ask myself how to turn off the "crazy character length" and "no spaces" -feature of content, that is created for textfields.

Each textfield of my generated nodes is mostly filled with just 1 word, that contains an unrealistic number of characters with "no" spaces.

Example:
wuvicreshiphovowubitodrecaphuliswugoclebeprushewiphusebratidrovasishicowracheracregoswethemespacrubrawugichedeuewacuprenesaphespuslushastimamathetapipheproswesetriprubuswaduwusledribiviswiuefredrudruuedanaphahuprocowicastonohagibrotrunecitrusadrericreswab

This breaks layouts. And makes it really hard to work with it.

Why is that? Forcing users to use overflow:hidden is a nice idea - but how to turn it off?

In this moment I use jQuery to add spaces. Guess that's not the way the devs meant it to be used.

Thanks

Comment: No repro for me - I get paragraphs of latin sentences as produced by `Random::paragraphs`, for textareas, and a single sentence of the same for standard text fields

Comment: this is strange. I use devel generate in almost every project. And never ever have seen it differently. Are you sure? Could language settings - in my case "german" - be an issue? Text Areas look good... it's just with textfields like that.

Comment: Yeah totally sure, I just generated 50 nodes on a test site to check. Don't forget "title" is a textfield, so if your titles are working but other text fields aren't, it's possibly something custom to your installation. Yeah it could be language-related, I'm not in a position to test that right now

Comment: It has to be a custom textfield (not the title). The title works as well

Comment: I’ve never seen devel do this under English setting.

Comment: Then you better check twice... -> There you go:
https://dmf4n.ply.st/node/7/edit
usr+pssw=admin.

Comment: So can this be treated as "bug"?

Comment: @mogio I'm with you! While doing a **generate content** might give you some nice values, **generate users** gives you the garbage values that you describe which break layout and looks terrible when trying to demonstrate to a client. In one of our D8 projects, we have lots of user questions during the registration process, capturing text in plain text fields (not text areas). That's how you can replicate Mogio's issue. I've spent a good hour trying to find a solution, but found nothing. Drupal Console can be used to bulk-create users, but it doesn't fill out any custom user fields.

Comment: Regarding what I tried, [realistic_dummy_content](https://www.drupal.org/project/realistic_dummy_content) only handles images. The only semi-feasible solution would be porting the [Devel Generate Text Settings](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_generate_text_settings) module from D7 to D8.